# ruby on rails undefined method 'valid' when using update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am using the same commands that I previously used in successful projects but now I suddenly can't validate any updates to the object(in this case, User). Everything else works fine but any attempt to check my validations for an update results in this error-

'undefined method `valid?' for # '

It is finding successfully finding the user and if I skip the .valid? statement then it will update, just without checking any of my model validations. I recently switched from SQLite to PostgreSQL, I am not sure if that's giving me the problem. I am new to Ruby but I couldn't find anything on this specific problem.

Please let me know if I should include the entirety of my controller or any of my model but as my create works fine, I feel like all the relative code is just in this little section-

class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    puts "#Is this working???!! #{@user}" ///prints #Is this working???!! #<User:0x00000001f24468>
    @user = User.update(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
        redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}"
    else
        flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
        redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}/edit" 
    end
  end
 private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord **update(id, attributes)**

Updates an object (or multiple objects) **and saves it to the database, if validations pass.** The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

Then, you can do this checking `if @user.update(user_params)`

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # Find user
  if @user.update(user_params) # Update user if validations pass
      redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}"
  else
      flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}/edit" 
  end
end
```

Or, you can call the update method directly in your model class, but the first argument must be the user ID

```
User.update(params[:id], user_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
@user = User.update(user_params)
```

If you put in your check after, you would see: `#Is this working???!! true`, which would ironically enough inform you that it's not working.

That's because `User.update(user_params)` returns true or false depending on whether it is successful or not. This means your `@user` object is now simply either true or false, which you can't call `valid` on.

If you want to handle successfully updating / failing to do so, try:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}"
  else
    flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
    redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}/edit" 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your quick answers. I was replying to tell you that I already tried that and it worked but did not validate. But as two of you told me the same thing, I decided to test it out again and the validations did indeed work this time so thank you (although I definitely have a user with an email of 'asdf' from last time).

Intestering enough, I found another answer although I have no idea why it worked. I added another puts statement after the update and realized my object had been converted to an array so I came up with this other (worse) alternative answer-

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    puts "#Is this working???!! #{@user}"
    @user = User.update(user_params)
    puts "#Is this working???!! #{@user}" ///prints #Is this working???!! [#<User id: 2, name: "James Dean", etc..>] 
    if @user[0].valid?
        redirect_to "/users/#{@user[0].id}"
    else
        flash[:errors] = @user[0].errors.full_messages
        redirect_to "/users/#{@user[0].id}/edit" 
    end
  end
```